# Issue in changing the location via latitude and longitude

Tags: android, location

I am facing an issue in my application regarding  the latitude and longitude.
My code is as follows:-

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                    getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {

                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


                Toast.makeText(
                        CheckInSOSMessageService.this,
                         "Location has been Changed now.....................", 0)
                        .show();

                isLocationChanged=true;

                    }

                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                        Bundle extras) {
                }

                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                }

                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

                }
            };

            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

In the above code everything is working fine.The **onLocationChanged** method executes when the location gets change.But my problem is that when i move the device from one place to another,location changes and the toast notification seems at the device but the **onLocationChanged** method executes several times **continuously** even my device is in **idle** position now due to which the toast notification appears again and again .It irritates me a lot.I want that when once the location **changes** the above method will executes only **once** and after moving the device again then it will executes.This is my requirement.Guys please help me to sort out this problem.Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: What are you using isLocationChanged for? You could use that variable but a better idea would be to unregister the listener in order to conserve battery.

Comment: I#m not very familar with the Location API of Android but what I could imagine is, that if you move your device the location will be changed more than one time. May you could save the last values of long and lat and compare them with the new ones. If the diference is big enough print your post. Only an idea, dont know if it's true

Answer (score 0):

Even if your phone is at the same position all the time the location will change and will trigger onLocationChanged. That's because the GPS Signal is jumpy, because of f.e. reflection of the signal on a building. You will never get the exact same location in moderate time intervals.

To avoid that you could temporarly save the location and compare it with the new location. If the distance between them hits a defined boarder use the new location.

Another suggestion is to avoid requests like

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Because this will spam a lot and is very resource intensive. Try some different minTime and minDistance values which fit your approach. Then the onLocationChanged will not be triggered every 0ms.

EDIT:

If you want a location update every minute than use the request like this.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 1000, locationListener);
```

You will get a update now every minute and every kilometer. Because it's not possible to request an update without a minDistance, just set it high enough.

Comment: Hello Steve!! Actually I want to send the data to the server when the location changed.If there is no changement occur with in a minute then the data will not be send to the server.Similarly again when the location changed again the data will be send to the server.So I just want to recognize that whether the location gets change or not??Please help me to solve thios issue.I will definetly accept your answer.

Comment: But How can i test the application?? Is is necessary for me to go beyond 1 km and then test the application?

Comment: You will receive an update if 1 minute is gone or the distance is beyond 1 km

Comment: Thanks Steve!! I would like to ask one more question that I am starting the default location service through this line of code:-
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                    getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

Now I want to stop the location service after using it because it consump the large amount of battery.How can i achieve that??

Comment: The request is the ressource hungry part. Just remove the listener from the manager. LocationManager.removeUpdates(listener);

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared Preferences to update current location and compare the current location from sharedPrefs using location.distanceTo(loc) after you a get a significant distance run your logic.